# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError using Wildfly, Maven, Rest?

Tags: eclipse, rest, maven, wildfly

I have 2 Maven projects, and let's say I'm using Project2 as a dependency in Project1.
Project2 is using Java Security and has some encrypting methods.
I ran the command mvn install in Project2 and then this is how I am adding the dependency in Project1:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId> myProject2groupId </groupId>
  <artifactId> myProject2artifactId </artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

And I added this in Project2 pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            <finalName>ProjectJARs/project</finalName>
            </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

The import of the classes and methods of Project2 in Project1 are perfectly working, giving me no errors when I try to compile as a Java Application and printing in console.
But when I'm running it on the Wildfly server and applying GET/POST methods from my rest endpoints, it gives me this error:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: simmetricClasses/SimmetricCriptography
```

(In Project1 Maven Dependencies I can see Project1's folder with this [without test code])

Can someone help me with this error?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What type is your deployment? WAR, EAR?

Comment: The deployment I'm having is a WAR

Comment: Have you checked your WAR to ensure you've got the `WAR/WEB-INF/lib/myProject2artifactId-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` is present?

Comment: I don't have anything in my lib folder. Is it that the error? How could I solve it? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Can you share the pom.xml of your WAR?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, with my WAR do you mean my project2 pom.xml?

Comment: I posted my pom.xml in the answers. Thanks

Comment: The `maven-jar-plugin` configuration looks a bit suspect. Also I would think the artifact itself should be `<packaging>war</packaging>` as you want it to be a deployment.

Answer (score 0):

This is the pom.xml of the project I want to use as a module:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mygroupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifactId</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            <finalName>ProjectJARs/project</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build> 
  <properties>
 <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

</project>
```

Is this correct?